# Message count is not zero even after all messages are consumed and acknowledged

Tags: activemq-artemis, stomp.py

We have containerized ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0 and deployed it as a K8s deployment for [KEDA](https://keda.sh/docs/2.4/scalers/artemis/).

We use STOMP using stomp.py python module. The ACK-mode is set as `client-individual` and `consumerWindowSize` = 0 on the connection. We are promptly acknowledging the message as soon as we read it.

The problem is, sometimes, the message count in the web console does not become zero even after all the messages are actually consumed and acknowledged. When I browse the queue, I don't see any messages in it. This is causing KEDA to spin up pods unnecessarily. Please refer to the attached screenshots I attached in [the JIRA for this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3416).

Comment: Given that there's already a Jira open for this I recommend you work with the ActiveMQ developer community there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue in my application code. My requirement was one queue listener should consume only one message and exit gracefully. So, soon after sending ACK for the consumed message, I disconnected the connection, instead of waiting for the sleep duration to disconnect.

Thanks, Justin, for spending time on this.